# How do I output a string with spaces in between all characters recursively? In Python

Tags: python, recursion

I need to get an input from the user, and I need to print out each character in the input with a space, but using a recursion. How would I go about this?

```
inputNum = input("Enter a number: ")
def extractDigits(n):
lastNum = n[-1]
if n == lastNum:
    return ''
else:
    return n + '' + extractDigits(n[0])
print(extractDigits(inputNum))
```

My hope was that if I were to input "12345" with this function it would output "1 2 3 4 5 " but it still outputs as "12345". I'm trying to do this without for loops as well.

Comment: Among other things, you need `n + ' '` instead of n + `''`

Answer (score 1):

If you want a recursive function, you can do:

```
def extractDigits(n):
    if len(n) == 1:
        return n[-1]
    else:
        return n[0] + ' ' + extractDigits(n[1:])
```

Output:

```
extractDigits("12345")
# '1 2 3 4 5'
```

However, while pretty, recursive functions don't perform that well.

For example,

```
def extractDigits(n):
    return ' '.join(n)
```

performs much much faster.

Answer (score 0):

simple use join method.

```
inputNum=input("enter a number:")
num=" ".join(inputNum)
#look there  is a space bitween double qoutes
print(num)
#input: 123456
#output:1 2 3 4 5 6
```